# Ruby rails add field to form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby on rails and JavaScript. I want to create a form in which one field can have more than one "object". In my example an employee can add multiple formations.

Just to let you know, I don't know much in JavaScript and I am not an expert in Web languages. So please explain to me what are my problems in the following code.

This is the code in my employe _form.html.erb

```
<div id="formationSet" class="form-group row">
</div>
<a href="javascript:" id="addNewFormation">Add Formations</a>
```

this is my code in employeFormation.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addNewFormation').click(function(){
        $('div#formationSet').append('<div class ="FormationsForm"><input type="text" class="input-large" placeholder="Caption">'+
            '<button class="removeNewFormation" type="button">remove</button>    </div>');
    });

    $("div#formationSet").on('click', '.removeNewFormation', function(){
        $(this).closest('.FormationsForm').remove();
    });
});
```

and this is my code in application.js

```
//= require employeFormation
```

what I actually want is that when I click on addFormation its add a field below the other and I can remove it and is added to my object when I create the new employee

Thanks you for your answer.

Edit: corrected some typo in the code (thanks to KKK). But its still not working

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code was that you refer a wrong id in javascript. In your HTML the id is `FormationSet` and in javascript you try to append form into `formationSet` div. Change the id in HTML and it works fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addNewFormation').click(function(){
        $('div#formationSet').append('<div class ="FormationsForm"><input type="text" class="input-large" placeholder="Caption">'+
            '<button class="removeNewFormation" type="button">remove</button>    </div>');
    });

    $("div#formationSet").on('click', '.removeNewFormation', function(){
        $(this).closest('.FormationsForm').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formationSet" class="form-group row">
</div>
<a href="javascript:" id="addNewFormation">Add Formations</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. But I was wondering what this line do : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` Do I need it?

Comment: No, you don't need it. (I hope you have already included jQuery in your app). I included this so that the code snippet works here. Unless it won't work since we need jQuery to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Above ruby 4.0 aparently $(document).ready dont get notify as before. So I had to change it like this:

```
var ready = function() {
    $('#addNewFormation').click(function(){
        $('div#formationSet').append('<div class ="FormationsForm"> <%=     f.label :email %> \n <%= f.text_field :email %>' +

        '<button class="removeNewFormation" type="button">remove</button></div>');
    });


    $("div#formationSet").on('click', '.removeNewFormation', function(){
        $(this).closest('.FormationsForm').remove();
    });
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:change', ready);
```